What makes a question about a country or leader's armed conflict goals/aims/exit strategies "opinion-based"?
Yes, the question has been reopened, but really this was more about asking about objective criteria that we can refer to for future cases.  Think of this as a (to me) particularly representative example of unclear metrics, when compared to other similar questions.

(Was closed, twice. Has been reopened) - opinion-based
+14 What is Netanyahu's exit strategy from the war in Gaza and Lebanon, and a potential confrontation with Iran? - Politics Stack Exchange

I'm sorry, but we can not read Netanyahu's mind. So any answers will be pure speculation that can not be proven correct or incorrect


This is actually worse than the similar questions about Russia. While Russia is not a credible source of information about Russia because Putin lies non-stop, at least his motivations have been stated, however dishonestly. Netanyahu's been fairly secretive about his end goals, almost treating them as war secrets. So this question is literally inviting speculation in a vacuum.


This specific question template is almost always an invitation to speculate. The only way it may be answerable is if there are specific quotes which are too convoluted and the question is asking to parse through them.


Talking about someone's long-term goals doesn't answer the question about what the exit strategy is. It touches on the question of what the end-goal is. But that's a very, very different question than what the exit strategy is

Remained open
+46 What could Russia hope to gain by continuing their war against Ukraine?

(me) For other Russian goals and motivations, you'd have to read the mind of the only person who matters: Putin. Since that is not possible, this devolves into multiple opinions, despite being the $64B question. Upvoted, but sadly well-deserving of closure. Welcome aboard.

No, my vote did not carry the day, it remained happily open.
+8 (closed, reopened) / What is Russia's stated military strategy in Ukraine as of early 2023?
Now, this is one is actually a funny one.  I voted to close it, because, military secrets and all that:  unknowable.  It was reopened and in no danger of getting closed, so I answered it.  Most of my answer consisted of explaining why asking predictions about military strategy (rather than citing national goals) couldn't be expected to result in informed answers. Then I added some predictions based on my best guesses (no one minded).
+65 Exit strategies for the Ukraine war
+19 Are there military arguments why Russia would blow up the Kakhovka dam?
+11 Are there military arguments why Ukraine would blow up the Kakhovka dam?
Those two Dams Qs were quite contentious.  It started with the Russian motivations Q, which was contested but popular.  Then someone opened the Ukraine motivations Q, which was criticized but survived due to the illogicality of accepting only the Russian one.
Eventually the community settled down to listing possible advantages on both sides, (without any official statements to go on).
+19 What is Iran's long-term objective in the Middle East?
No one commented on unknowability, though there are admittedly 3 VTCs at this point.  Answers accusing Iran of ill intent?  Quite upvoted.
+14 Why is US supporting ISIS in Syria while opposing it in Iraq?
Seems to have survived just fine despite a) its premise being wrong and b) if it was right, it would be secret.
+8 What is China's objective in militarizing the South China Sea?
There was one comment about discrediting and/or being hard to reason about:

This Question should be closed because "The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician." and because it is asking for opinions on a country's objectives, for which a fact-based Answer is usually impossible (barring something like a massive Wikileak of internal communications).

If the lack of clear info to go on was really a hard criteria, then, yes, China is very opaque and especially on this subject.  This objection didn't gather much steam however.  We got 5 opinion-based answers (including one of mine).  Only the ones supportive of China really got DVs.  Everybody happy.
+15 What is Israel's strategy in invading the Gaza strip?
The prototype for this one, seems like.  Seems to me, if a leader wants to X, Y, Z and has only achieved X and Z, then their "exit strategy" will be to either achieve Y or downgrade it.
If it was a valid Q to ask what Israel wanted to achieve 4 weeks in, it seems quite valid, including most of all to the Israeli public, what it wants to achieve 1 year in.  I assume someone is asking Netanyahu exactly that and I assume he has had to answer something.

You get the idea.
I don't mind if people vote based on whatever metric they want, for whatever reasons, and that includes their bias for or against the country or leader that is being asked about.
But, once the ritual incantations have been said: ("what have officials stated?", "what did leader X say?", "has leader Y explained?") and assuming the question itself is asked in a non-pushy way (no mean feat, but one that the OP did manage here), what makes it so some of these questions have managed to remain open, while others don't?
Yes, I get that military secrets would be off limit (which why some of these probably should have been shut down). But a leader telling his country what they are fighting for is generally to be expected.
Heck, Bush did it when invading Iraq.  And Afghanistan.  Presumably, when you know what the goals are, you know when they'll be met (or not).  Would this question have been acceptable by a mere change of "exit strategy" to "war goals/war aims?".
Would a 2019 question asking about what the US goals/exit strategy were in Afghanistan have been off topic?  I am sure the American public had plenty of those in that timeline.  And I am sure the government/military would have least have mouthed some platitudes.
Assuming the question the question is worded neutrally and/or the asker is open to making suggested adjustment, what criteria can the community settle on to base the acceptance or rejection of these types of questions?  Are they all off-limit?  All in scope, if asked properly?  What adjustments would have made this question acceptable?
Lifted from the comments:

The only difference I can see is that in all other questions the positions of states is asked for instead of single persons.

Good catch.  However, is this what this one was about?  Would "What is Israel's exit strategy...?" be OK then?

FWIW, personally, I don't see much the difference between a country's foreign policy intents and their current leader's foreign policy intents.  Trump might be exceptional, but I would consider a "What is Trump intending wrt Mexico and X?" to be functionally equivalent to "What is the US intending wrt Mexico and X?", under a Trump presidency.  If it was a US public sentiment Q, why then "What do polls say about Mexico and X?"
But maybe others lean towards closure/keeping open on that basis?

p.s.  I am not all that interested in what the close voters' motivations were, on this particular question, in isolation.  I am more interested in whether the community can articulate some clear guidance on what's acceptable or not so that future questions are easier to defend or close.
What I'd like to see is how people reason through their perceived characteristics of this type of question's content and its context to decide on open/close.  Does asking for country goals vs a leaders's matter?  Can a question be salvaged by "according to govt X's statements?".  Do we make a difference between asking about democratic leaderships (with a citeable history of campaign/PR statements) vs a secretive government that acts without much real explanations?  Even then China in South China seas is much less forthcoming about their goals than China wrt Taiwan.

Although I answered that Q, my guess is that people who VTC did so because it's only partly answerable based on public statements. And even then, statements don't always entirely disclose real goals etc.

That's why you have the incantation "what has government X said?"  It fools no one, but usually provides some extra HP for the question to survive.  I am not all that interested in what the close voters motivations were, I am more interested in whether the community can settle on some clear/non-capricious guidance on what's acceptable or not.

The only difference I can see is that in all other questions the positions of states is asked for instead of single persons. Of course the position of states is the (average?) position of persons. But maybe we want to replace Netanyahu in the title with Israel. It will come down to him anyway.

Decisions on war conduct might not be entirely down to Bibi. There is apparently a law about that https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89389/what-does-the-israeli-law-say-about-cabinet-votes-on-military-action Besides, he was sometimes threatened with [government] coalition partners pulling out.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Does that matter as much if the Q is phrased as being about Israeli (as opposed to Bibi) exit strategy?  Besides, in any democracy, war decisions are not entirely down to a leader's preferences, but the public-record interplay with their opponents/supporters/voters does throw light on their goals.

All the other examples are either for a whole country (Russia, Iran, Ukraine, China) or even more general (Exit strategies for the Ukrainian war). This question is on a single person's view only and even though this person is the PM of his country, he doesn't run his country alone. To get a broader and more meaningful basis of arguments, we could extend the question to ask for the whole of Israel (or the government of Israel, the same the government of Russia, Iran, ...). But that might influence existing answers.
We want interesting and useful questions that can be answered factually. This is the whole reason for some close reasons. For this we naturally have to refrain from speculation as much as possible. Questions about the future will always be speculative. We never really know what will happen. But then even if we just restrict ourselves on the past or on the facts, i.e. what people said, well they can lie of course. Netanyahu might not be honest about this strategies. Simply stating them without putting them in context would be naive. Putting them into the wrong context might only reflect personal bias or even be an attempt at influencing others.
I would say that all these questions are peculiar in that they
a) are of very high interest. Many people want to know more about it. And
b) contain very speculative answers with a relatively low information content. I seldomly learn something from these answers beyond the obvious (Russia wants to conquer Ukraine, Iran wants to destroy Israel).
Maybe we want to discuss in general how to make these Q&A pairs better, like being more clear about what we can and cannot say really.
And while I agree in principle that people should downvote answers more if they are bad, it's just not happening that people refrain from answering if they don't know. The lived experience is that people answer happily with speculations and/or their own opinions in the absence of reliable information. Downvoting that all will be lots of work.
Therefore I can understand that sometimes we rather close questions and we have to draw the line for this somewhere. In this specific case I voted to reopen and if some of the at least 14 people who upvoted do that too, the question should soon be open again. I wish this question and all such future questions were more about the whole country and not about a single person.

Interesting!  Re. a)  Yes, their high-interest quota is what gets them (re)open.  b) low info/high speculation answers.  I think we can look split that up.  First, you  may totally know the background of a war.  Many of us do, on Israel-Hamas.  However, I do bet many Americans users first learned about their 1953 CIA overthrow of the Iranian PM here.  Or what's Azerb doing wrt Nagorno-K? Do u know? Sometimes it's obvious and sometimes it's mostly speculative feel-goodery:  the recent Iranian Q's answers fit that.  Anyway, the obvious is OK, if sourced.  The speculative/overbiased can be DVd

Re high speculation.  That's also a mixed bag.  Bibi has left a long trail of statements about his goals, as can be expected from a leader of a democracy.  Xi has been less than forthcoming about what China wants out of the Spratleys (which did not kill that question) beyond the laughable 9-dash line (something not every user will know about).  Xi has been pretty forthcoming regarding his intents to reunify Taiwan, if not the means.  Part of that would be the CCP's frequent assertion that a declaration of independence means war, which does carry information to users less familiar w subject...

@ItalianPhilosopher "Bibi has left a long trail of statements about his goals, as can be expected from a leader of a democracy." But still he doesn't run Israel alone, neither do Xi or Vladimir theirs. Therefore it's better to ask for the whole country.

So, does that mean that "What is Israel's exit strategy from the war in Gaza and Lebanon, and a potential confrontation with Iran? - Politics Stack Exchange" would have made this Q, and similars, better?

I'm curious why you voted to reopen that question, when you've quite clearly articulated why it was unsuitable.

@CharlieEvans As I said in the answer: you have to draw the line somewhere. Unsuitable is too harsh a word in this case. Although I would prefer if it was about Israel more than about Netanyahu I think even as it is, it's still acceptable, but not great. Still I wanted to give feedback here why some people might see it critically and what could be done to improve similar cases in the future. The SE model is based on consensus. Because everyone has only a single close/reopen vote some kind of majority decision is reached. Meta discussions help with forming opinions and increase consistency.

All of the questions you refer to are unsuitable for this site. Each of them satisfies at least one of the close criteria, and several meet more than one. Related to this is the fact that they tend to precipitate very poor quality answers, in which the respondents propound their opinions on the causes/morality/progress/outcomes of the conflict in question. I'm not going to discuss each of the cited questions in detail, but essentially they fail in at least one of the following ways:

They ask for information that would only be known to the leader of a state, or possibly high level politicians and military officers.
They ask about public statements (typically in a fairly transparent attempt to evade the above objection), but are far too broad in their terms of reference and answers end up either making minimal use of public statements, or cobbling together many blocks of loosely related text in a way which is of dubious utility.
They aren't really about politics or government at all, but rather military tactics and strategy. There's some overlap here, but not enough to justify many of the questions related to wars.
The questions is a thinly veiled attempt to discredit one side of the conflict, or just push the author's own particular view on the matter.
They openly invite opinion and speculation, not really settling on a single questions but rather asking something along the lines of "what's going on here?".

In general, questions about ongoing, or recent, events, especially contentious ones, are likely to fall foul of the rules on suitability. This is particularly true for armed conflicts, which are the most contentious of occurrences and tend to result in a low information, but high interest, environment which is ripe for speculation. People tend to ask (and answer) questions that interest them, but the site is a Q&A about politics (and government) specifically, not a forum on current affairs.

Well, you're consistent and give clear criteria.  Thing is, in practice, from the samples given, people don't close those questions near as consistently.  A strong thread seems to be:  querying about "popular" countries cause some to VTC, while "unpopular" countries are OK to be scrutinized and questions are not judged as harshly.  And really, it highly depend on the circumstances:  a question which starts out early on with a negative comment as to opinion-based will likely have a rougher closure ride than one where that did not happen.

They ask about public statements (typically in a fairly transparent attempt to evade the above objection),.  I tend to agree, calling that an "incantation", myself.  However, while it doesn't make a question much better on its own, it can be a useful reminder for answers not to engage in overmuch unsourced speculation.

Frankly this would mean banning a much broader spectrum of Qs. Take https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72255/why-is-the-war-in-ukraine-considered-a-russian-fiasco for instance. Impossible to answer without some assumptions about war goals.

Also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74211/what-is-the-pacifist-position-on-ukraine that you have answered. How can one discuss "concessions to Russia" if can't assume what their goals are etc.

@ItalianPhilosopher I agree with your analysis on what kind of questions tend to get closed. I don't think there's much that can be done about that really, given the SE model and demographics of the user base. I've tried to set out my own criteria here, but obviously I can't force others to follow them. I have some sympathy for the idea that, as closing occurs in a biased pattern we should be reluctant to close, in the interest of fairness. However, my own preference is for eliminating low quality questions, over avoiding site-wide bias, if a choice has to be made.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Yes, it would mean closing more questions, I consider that desirable. The question you link is quite heavily downvoted, and was closed before you and others reopened it, so it doesn't seem like an obvious example of a "good" question that would be caught by my criteria.

@IVFcomesfromthetip I actually thought that question was quite marginal, but was just about concrete enough to be meaningfully answered. Regarding your specific question, I think it's quite possible to offer concessions without knowing what the other party wants. It is analogous to how one can give someone a gift without knowing what they like. Whether the concessions are enough, or the gift is well received, is a different matter.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Not sure about your choice of questions.  The one about Ukraine was a push, from someone who had just posted another push:  "Why is Ukraine struggling so much to beat Russia?".  It really should have been kept closed.  The second one, "What is the pacifist position?", is just not in the same category of questions we are talking about, as it is built around asking what public statements are.

@ItalianPhilosopher: this answer says that public statements are used as a fig for asking/answering a different question.

I've voted to reopen the question and think the close reason is silly. One could reasonably argue the question cannot be verified by public sources, but calling it opinion-based is unfair.
If Netanyahu has an exit strategy, he evidently has not made it public (which is why nobody seems to know what that strategy is, and by extension why people seem to think the question is opinion-based). But that just means the correct answer is "we don't know what Netanyahu's exit strategy is", and if Netanyahu were one day to elaborate on it, then the answer would change. Closing this question as opinion-based questions would imply that even if Netanyahu spells out his exit strategy, the question would still be unanswerable.
As it is the problem is not with the question, but rather the answers; if you must downvote, downvote the answers that are based on opinion, but leave the question alone.

I do think Netanyahu has made his goals clear and can be quoted.  That particular objection was specious. What he hasn't indicated is under which conditions he would leave if those goals are not met.  Re. "if you must downvote, downvote the answers that are based on opinion"  - my sentiments exactly:  other questions with similar characteristics have been accepted, but that doesn't mean answers clearly based on opinions always get a pass under them.

OK, but how do you come to the conclusion it's not opinion-based?  Do you hold that belief with most of these types of questions?  Or ones like this one?  And how do you figure we can get any answers that are worthy if those have no information sources to be written from?

@ItalianPhilosopher: I ask myself this: "Can this question be answered solely with respect to observed behavior (including, obviously, statements by the parties in question), or would any answer be dependent on speculation about parties internal states or motivations?" It's actually not too difficult to do that, with a bit of practice, but it often runs afoul of people's emotional reactivity.

@ItalianPhilosopher: Note, for instance, that we can't even point out that the likely outcome of the current Gaza tactics will be rendering most of Gaza uninhabitable, not without it being flagged and removed. It's a pickle…

Speaking personally, I invoke the 'opinion-based' criteria when I believe that someone is asking a 'why' question that can't be reduced or translated into a 'what' or 'how' question. As a general rule, we don't know why any persons or groups do what they do unless they explicitly state their reasoning and goals. We can sometimes interpolate likely outcomes from what we see them do, and we can recognize patterns in their behavior that can clue us in to what they think is relevant and important. But trying to determine why often invokes our own biases about the situation, or can lead us into conspiracy thinking.
For an example, on this particular topic we can safely say that a likely outcome of Netanyahu's actions is that the Gaza Strip will be reduced to being largely uninhabitable, at least at anything near the population density it originally had. That's interpolation, not speculation; if Israel continues its ongoing actions most of Gaza will end up as rubble, with little to no infrastructure to support it. But we don't know the 'why'; whether this would be Netanyahu's intention, or arbitrary excesses of overzealous commanders, or a wider plot by Israel to claim Gaza and annex and repurpose it, or just sheer vengeance playing itself out. The expressed claim is that Netanyahu wants to root out Hamas, but since no one ever specifies what 'rooting out' means in practical terms that claim doesn't say much of interest. it could be applied to anything from outright genocide to holding and anti-mamas bake sale.
Rule of thumb in politics; listen to what people say with skepticism, watch what they do with cynicism, and don't bother challenging them where they're expecting (and girding for) battle.

FWTW, the Israeli media itself seem more willing to advance the 'why'. E.g. https://www.timesofisrael.com/weve-had-the-victory-pictures-but-how-is-israel-aiming-to-actually-win-the-war/

"no one ever specifies what 'rooting out' means in practical terms" -- From ToI: "In the north of Gaza, with the focus on Jabaliya at present, the IDF is in the process of displacing the entire civilian population. [...] monitoring Gazans as they evacuate, and arresting Hamas suspects among them as they go, and gradually turning the area into a kind of closed military zone [...] The goal appears to be to create a dependably safe, Hamas-free northern Gaza. [...]
If that sounds vague and improbable, it’s partly because official Israel isn’t talking publicly about how this might play out [...]"

@IVFcomesfromthetip: Well, note that even that statement doesn't explicitly tell whether the goal is to remove the civilian population while they root out Hamas and then allow the civilians back (which is harsh, but not unreasonable) or to remove the civilians permanently and annex north Gaza. And it doesn't really explain the level of violence in the region; Israel could have given civilians plenty of opportunity to leave, and then entered north Gaza surgically, rather than beginning a full scale assault right over the civilian's heads. Actions speak a bit louder than words, no?

I think Bibi himself hasn't figured it out. He's being pressured by his far-right coalition partners to not allow any Palestinians back in the north, on one hand, OTOH the Biden admin has found some balls to send him a formal letter that some US aid to the IDF might be suspended if not enough food is allowed to reach the north etc. (Conveniently, the letter was sent before the US election, but any decision would only have to be made after.)

we can safely say that a likely outcome of Netanyahu's actions is that the Gaza Strip will be reduced to being largely uninhabitable...  OK, but we don't know if that was the goal though that seems to be your opinion.  Mix terrorism, anti-terrorist operations in an urban context and trapped civilians, and you'll likely end up with something like Mosul, Raqqa or Gaza.  Now, it seems to be your opinion that this is intentional (esp. since you commented to that effect on the Q), but this answer, as ever unsourced, does little to give credibility to keeping this style of question open.

@ItalianPhilosopher: I don't generally make assumptions about mind states, despite what you might think. I make inferences about trajectories rfom behavior, and the current progress of this war is going to leave large parts of Gaza uninhabitable, whether that's the intention or not. This is the problem with opinion-based ('why') questions: they lead people to speculate about unknowable motivations and ignore or write-off observable, predictable consequences.

The question never asked whether Gaza was going to be inhabitable or not.  Depopulated or not.  Bringing that up wouldn't have answered the original question.  Doesn't answer this one either.  If you could haved linked to something Bibi said about "let's make it too unpleasant to live here", then it would have belonged on the original answer.  But that goal is mostly only partially admitted to by Mssrs. Smotrich and Ben-Gvir.  It is is anybody's guess how much influence they have on overall Israeli strategy.  Too much, on that we can both agree!
